# Unable to get a subdomain working in Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

We have our main site hosted in AWS and use Route 53 for the dns settings.  I have a subdomain that I need to point to a SquareSpace site.

I have created a seperate zone in Route 53 and was able to add a cname record for the subdomain, but only with the www. prefix.  The site is then working with www., but not normaly.

Whenever I try to add the a cname as an alias to the www domain I get the following error:

RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name utilities.housemaster.com. is not permitted as it conflicts with other records with the same DNS name in zone utilities.housemaster.com.

Any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: Why did you create a separate hosted zone?

Answer (score 1):

The error message already told you what the problem was - utilities.housemaster.com is already defined. You can see that [here](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=dnsrec&host=utilities.housemaster.com). It looks like NS and SOA records exist.

You need to find where the subdomain is defined already and either add the records you need, or delete it and recreate.